# Access Rights: Copying Sheets with inserted images between accounts

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

If we have a Google Sheets document that has inserted images/drawings in one Google Drive account and we use the API to copy it to another Google Drive account, how do we ensure that the new account has access to the inserted items?

At the moment it appears that the first time the user opens the newly copied document, the image content isn't displayed and when they try to edit the embedded images/drawings they get a warning that they don't have access to those items.  However the second time they open the Google Sheet they then can see the items and have access to edit them.

Is this an issue with Google Drive as a whole?  Is there anything we can do to work around it?

Narrowed things down a bit without using the API...

1. Create a sheet and insert a new drawing.
2. Copy the sheet.
3. Share the copy with someone else.
4. They don't have permission to see the drawing.

If you share the original they can see the drawing in the original.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Google Sheets itself, since you replicated the problem using the UI as well. The best place to report product issues is the [Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets).